# What do you call a constructor with an rvalue reference parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

> A move constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is T&&, const T&&, volatile T&&, or const volatile T&&, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.

What would you call a constructor that took an rvalue reference to a different type:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Bar
{
    std::string bs;
    std::vector<char> bv;

};

struct Foo {
    std::string fs;
    std::vector<char> fv;

    Foo(Bar && b)
    : fs(std::move(b.bs))
    , fv(std::move(b.bv))
    {}
};
```

Comment: It has no official name. I'd just call it a constructor for `Foo` that takes an r-value reference of `Bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call it a "constructor".

Functions of all kinds can take rvalue references to types, just like they can take lvalue references, values, etc. They only get special names when the compiler/language needs to treat them specially. And the compiler doesn't treat this constructor any differently from any other function that takes an rvalue.

Though generally speaking, the *meaning* of such a constructor is that it *will* move from the `Bar` that it is given. Indeed, you should never take an rvalue reference parameter that you don't move (or forward) from. Whether it is moving the `Bar` into itself, or the move happens as a subsidiary action to create the internal data of `Foo`, or whatever else is up to the constructor's implementation.

Comment: This constructor can also be called a [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Technically, yes, but in C++11, *any* non-explicit constructor that isn't a copy/move/default one is a converting constructor.

Comment: A "sort-of move constructor", then :)

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I guess that term lost its power in C++11.

Comment: I've seen something like this called the "converting move constructor". @NicolBolas Well, technically, non-explicit copy/move/default constructors are converting constructors too.